# Python Bokeh set axis minimum only, without setting the whole range

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

It's nice that I don't have to specify the axis ranges when I want to do a quick and easy plot, and that Bokeh does it automatically (like every other plotting library), but is there to set an axis *minimum* only, while letting Bokeh automatically set the maximum? I know I can set the full range by setting `Figure.y_range` or whatever, but I can't seem to set just the y-minimum, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `start` value of the `y_range` after defining the figure.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.line([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4])
p.y_range.start=2
show(p)
```

| **default** | **y_range.start=2** |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image: y_range.start == 2] |

Comment: Need:   from bokeh.plotting import figure, show   and   show(p)